# JasperException: Unable to read TLD "META-INF/c.tld" from JAR file

Tags: java

I've created a custom tag and included the following maven dependency in order to get the required java classes (tagsupport, etc.)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I run the project using tomcat, I am getting the following exception "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to read TLD "META-INF/c.tld" from JAR file".

I've looked at lots of forums and everybody is suggesting to remove jsp-api.jar from the lib to fix this problem. However, I need this jar file in order to use TagSupport and extend it for my custom tag. Any ideas on how to overcome this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this dependency in "provided" scope :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```